# @Embeddable class attributes from different Entities

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

COUNTRY and ADDRESS table has one-to-many relationship and ADDRESS and COUNTRY has many-to-one relationship. COUNTRY table has Id and Country Names. Address table has Country(has country codes from COUNTRY table) and NAME.
NAME and COUNTRY are unique keys in the ADDRESS table.

How to add Address Entity's NAME to CountryAddress Embeddable class? (  embeddable attributes are from different entities)

```
    @Entity    
    public class Country {

        @Column(name = "COUNTRY")    
        private String countryName;        

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "country")        
        public Map<CountryAddress, Address> getAddressMap() {    
            return addressMap;    
        }


    @Embeddable
    public class CountryAddress {

        @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
        private String countryName;


        //  Need to add  NAME from Address 


    }

}



@Entity
public class Address {

    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name; 

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY")
    private Country country;   


}
```

Comment: JPA simply persists your classes. You don't design your classes using some "JPA magic". If you want a name field in there then put one

Comment: It needs JPA magic for composite key as a key for a Map

Comment: There is no such magic. Just design your classes as you normally would